# Should I write <!DOCTYPE HTML> on all of the php including pages?

Tags: php, html, web, include

I have included the header and then i wrote the main section in html and i again include the footer. But my browser's developer tools say that its on the quirks mode and the problem is my document doesn't have a DOCTYPE

And this is the code

```
<?php ini_set('include_path', '/storage/emulated/0/1_code/1_web/server/1/998/root/include');
include("header.php"); 
?> 
<!DOCTYPE HTML>  
<html>  
  <head>    
    <title>paw</title>                                
    <link href="/css/index.css" rel="stylesheet">     
    <link href="fntsm/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">    
    <meta name="viewport" content="width = device-width , initial-scale = 1.0">  
  </head>
  <body>
    <main>      
      <section>uu</section>                                      
    </main>  
  </body>  
</html>                                                    
<?php include("footer.php"); ?>
```

This is my header:

```
<html>
  <header>
    <ul id="navbar">
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
  </header>
</html>
```

And I'm still working on it.  The footer is

```
<html>
  <footer  charset="rtl">
    all rights are served
    <a href="https://www.999blog.net">999blog.net</a>
    <br>
    using this website means you have read the
    <a> privacy and policy</a>.
    <br><br>
    <?php $thisyear = 2023 ; echo "&copy; $thisyear" ;
    if ($thisyear == date("Y")) {}
    else { echo"-"; echo date("Y");} ?>
    <br>

    <br>
    <a class="fab fa-telegram" href="https://t.me..."></a> &nbsp;
    <a class="fab fa-instagram" href="http://www.somethingjsh"></a> &nbsp;

    <br> &nbsp;
  </footer>
<html>
```

Comment: What is in your `header.php` file? Surely it would make sense for all this: `<!DOCTYPE HTML>  
<html>  
  <head>    
    <title>paw</title>                                
    <link href="/css/index.css" rel="stylesheet">     
    <link href="fntsm/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">    
    <meta name="viewport" content="width = device-width , initial-scale = 1.0">  
  </head>
  <body>` to be in the header, as you probably want something similar on every page, and you don't want to have to copy it to every file. That's the whole point of having a PHP header file, isn't it?

Comment: And then I'd imagine `footer.php` would contain `  </body>  
</html>` ...again so that you don't have to repeat that on every individual page.

Comment: It looks like you're outputting the header before, and the footer after, the main HTML page code.

Comment: Obviously we can't see your header and footer files (please [edit] your question) but I'm going to guess that you've already included some (perhaps different?) doctype and html tags in those. A HTML document should only have one Doctype, one html tag, one head and one body. Don't forget that what the browser receives, and tries to interpret as a single HTML document, is a combination of the output from all the included PHP scripts.

Comment: Oh THANK YOU SO MUCH. i think it was one of my big mistakes ADyson .

Comment: Thank you ADyson. I think my problem solved. Haha I'm a noob 